# When installing an old version of a package, can I install only compatible versions of dependent packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, teradata

I'm using Python 3.7.4 in a venv environment.
I ran `pip install teradataml==17.0.0.3` which installs a bunch of dependent packages, including `sqlalchemy`.
At the time, it installed `SQLAlchemy==2.0.2`.

I ran the below code, and received this error:
`ArgumentError: Additional keyword arguments are not accepted by this function/method.  The presence of **kw is for pep-484 typing purposes`

```
from teradataml import create_context 

class ConnectToTeradata:
    def __init__(self):
        
        host = 'AWESOME_HOST'
        username = 'johnnyMnemonic'
        password = 'keanu4life'

        self.connection = create_context(host = host, user = username, password = password)

    def __del__(self):
        print("Closing connection")
        self.connection.dispose()

ConnectToTeradata()
```

If I install `SQLAlchemy==1.4.26` before `teradataml`, I no longer get the error and successfuly connect.
This suggests `SQLAlchemy==2.0.2` is not compatible with `teradataml==17.0.0.3`.

I expected installing an older version of `teradataml` would also install older, compatible versions of dependent packages.
When I install `teradataml==17.0.0.3`, can I force only install compatible versions of dependent packages?

Comment: Just wondering if there is a solution. How could `pip` know what is compatible? It just relies on the requirements data. Yes, there is a risk that a major version change might bring incompatibility (like in your case `SQLAlchemy` 1.X vs 2.X) But at the time a package is released (including its requirements specification), it is not possible to know which future versions of some dependency will break the software. OTOH rejecting future major versions may cause other kind of problems (pulling in old unmaintained software).

Comment: The question is why do you install 2 year old `teradataml` version? Current version is 17.20.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are aware of the compatibility issues that were introduced in SQLAlchemy package 2.0.x versions. The new 2.0.x package directly affects the Teradata SQL dialect in the teradatasqlalchemy package. As a temporary measure, please downgrade SQLAlchemy to 1.4.46.

Teradata Engineering is working on making the teradatasqlalchemy package compatible with the newer versions and a new package is slated to be released in March 2023.